# Accessing event.target inside callback in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following class snippet:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.timeout = null;
}

search = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(
        function(){ console.log(e.target); },
        500
    );
}

<input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Search by title or author" 
    onKeyPress={this.search} />
```

I can't get the set timeout to print the value from the event, is there something that i should be doing but i'm not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)**.

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling)**:

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons.

Example:

```
function onClick(event) {
   console.log(event.type); // => "click"
   const eventType = event.type; // => "click"

   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(event.type); // => null
      console.log(eventType); // => "click"
   }, 0);    
}
```

> How to access the values inside callback?

**Storing value in a variable:**

If you want to access the value in timeout callback function then store the value in a variable and use that variable instead of directly using the event object.

```
function onClick(event) {

   console.log(event.type); // => "click"

   const { type } = event;

   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(type);   // => click
   }, 0);    
}
```

**Using event.persist():**

If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call **event.persist()** on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

```
function onClick(event) {

   event.persist();

   console.log(event.type); // => "click"

   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(event.type); // => click
   }, 0);    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
search = (e) => {
e.persist();
clearTimeout(this.timeout);
this.timeout = setTimeout(
    function(){ console.log(e); alert(e) },
    500
);
```

}

Judging from your code I think that you are using **babel-plugin-transform-class-properties**. In that case you don't need a constructor part.

Answer (score 2):

[SyntheticEvent - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

> Note: As of v17, e.persist() doesn’t do anything because the SyntheticEvent is no longer pooled.

After React v17, SyntheticEvent has no longer nullified the event.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your onKeypress method, but it might be a binding issue.  Try binding your search in the constructor.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.timeout = null;
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: ive updated the code to include the onkeypress method call

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to make the `timeout` as state?

My suggestion would be like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       timeout: null
    }
}

search = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(this.state.timeout);
    const timeout = setTimeout(
        function(){ console.log(e.target); },
        500
    );
    this.setState({timeout: timeout})

}
```