# Use setState on a object of state on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm using ReactJS and I need to change the status of the values ​​but the value property is in the state in this way:

```
this.state = {
         form:{
                name:{
                    value:''
                 }
              }  
         }
```

I tried it in different ways on the form like:

```
<TextInput
 name='form.name.value'
 value={this.state.form.name.value}
 onChange={value => this.onChange('name', value)}
/>


 onChange = (e) => { 
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

But never changes the value on state.

How can I do this? thanks!!!!!!

Comment: you used `TextInput` is it `react-native` or `reactjs` ? If `reactjs` and custom `input` field then show code of `TextInput`. Else `reactjs` input means HTML does not provide value directly in `onChange`

Comment: Text Input is just an input on ReactJS:

`<div className="input-field">
            <i className="material-icons prefix">{icon}</i>
            <input
                name={name}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                label={label}
                type={type}
            /> 
        </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have used the input field name is incorrect.In the `setState` it is considered as string rather than a `object.key`.

```
onChange= (e) => {
    let inputName = e.target.name;
     let inputValue = e.target.value;
     let updatedFormState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
     updatedFormState.form[inputName].value = inputValue;
     this.setState(updatedFormState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro but dont work: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null**

Comment: @OscarDev its because of SyntheticEvent concept, check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483492/accessing-event-target-inside-callback-in-react/45483658#45483658)

Comment: Thank you friend this works perfectly! I will review more about Object.assign that I have not used it for some time. Thank you!

Comment: I'm refactoring and it works great, thank you very much:

`let inputName = e.target.name;
        let inputValue = e.target.value;
        let form = {...this.state.form}
        form[inputName].value = inputValue;
        this.setState(form)`

Answer (score 1):

Your `onChange` function should be changed to

```
onChange = (e) => { 
    this.setState({ form: {...this.state.form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}})
}
```

Edit: I was able to run the below code successfully

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    form: {
       test: ""
    }
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      form: {
        ...this.state.form,
        [e.nativeEvent.target.name]: e.target.value,
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <TextInput 
       name='test'
       value={this.state.form.test}
       onChange={this.onChange}
      />
      <br/><br/>
      The State : {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
    </div>;
  }
}

const TextInput = (props) => {
  return <input type="text" {...props}/>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Edit: As per your new structure I have made the changes

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    form: {
       test: {
         value: "",
         type: "text"
       }
    }
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      form: {
        ...this.state.form,
        [e.nativeEvent.target.name]: {
            ...this.state.form[e.nativeEvent.target.name],
            value: e.nativeEvent.target.value
        },
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <CustomInput 
       name='test'
       value={this.state.form.test.value}
       onChange={this.onChange}
      />
      <br/><br/>
      The State : {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
    </div>;
  }
}

const CustomInput = (props) => {
  return <input {...props}/>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I tried with your example but the state change like this:

`State
 form:{...}
name: 'test'
`
And lost the object.

Comment: It works as long as the status is something like:

`State = { form: { name: " " } }`

But if the state is something like:


`State = { form: { name: {  value=" ",  type: " "} } }` Your solution overwrites the "name" object and leaves it without its properties:
`State = { form: { name:" " } }`

Comment: @OscarDev I have added my modified code snippet to accommodate your requirement

Answer (score 0):

In order to setState for a nested object you can follow the below approach as I think setState doesn't handle nested updates.

```
let form = {...this.state.form}
let name = [e.target.name];
form.name = e.target.value;
this.setState({form});
```

The idea is to create a dummy object perform operations on it and then replace the component's state with the updated object

Comment: I tried but I can change only the state of **name** if I add a new property like **form.surname.value** I cant use the input text.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your scenario but I think you are doing wrong practice.
Solution to you problem:

```
<TextInput
          name="form.name.value"
          value={this.state.form.name.value}
          onChange={(a, b) => this.handleTextChange(a, b)}
        />
```

Now `handleTextChange` like

```
 handleTextChange(name, value) {
    const arr = name.split(".");
    const obj = {
      [arr[2]]: value
    };
    const nameObj = {
      [arr[1]]: { ...obj }
    };

    console.log("fomr", nameObj);
    this.setState({ form: nameObj });
  }
```

Considering you customComponent

```
const TextInput = props => {
  return (
    <input
      name={props.name}
      onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
    />
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5vnnqo5xlx) working example

Comment: `form.name.value` string as name where doing wrong but may b this is because of scenario

Answer (score 0):

You need to use destructuring wiht es6:

I have created a working copy here: [CodePen InputForm](https://codepen.io/srinivasgurajala/pen/rrXOpe?editors=0010)

```
var sp = {...this.state.form};
sp.name.value = event.target.value;

this.setState({sp})
```