# Reactjs eslint rule must use destructuring state assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

```
class MyDrawer extends Component {
  const modalOpen = this.state;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer
          modal
          open={this.state.modalOpen} // <-- this line show error [eslint] Must use destructuring state assignment (react/destructuring-assignment)
          onClose={() => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })}
        >
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDrawer;
```

I tried change the line to be `const { modalOpen } = this.state;` but now Failed to compile.

How can i follow the rule and edit my code to be Compiled successfully?

Comment: The question is specific to JS in the first place. You chose a place to put `const` at random, it cannot be located there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` is in wrong place. Only class members can be declared inside `class MyDrawer extends Component {...}`, and `const` is not allowed there. Destructuring assignment should reside inside a function where a variable should be available:

```
  render() {
    const { modalOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer
          modal
          open={modalOpen}
          onClose={() => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })}
        >
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class MyDrawer extends Component {
  const { modalOpen } = this.state; //fixed

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Drawer
          modal
          open={ modalOpen } // fixed
          onClose={() => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })}
        >
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDrawer;
```

Comment: after fixed this two line, const { modalOpen } = this.state; still show a same error SyntaxError: \src\MyDrawer.js: Unexpected token (18:8)