# Can you make a copy of react state with destructuring?

Tags: reactjs, state, destructuring

If I need to make a copy of state to mutate in a function, do the following function the same?

```
const { mana } = this.state;
const mana = { ...this.state.mana };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Destructuring state/props in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055987/destructuring-state-props-in-react)

Comment: No, I know that the destructuring statement works. What I want to know is if the spread syntax functions identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those do *not* do the same thing. The first line doesn't do any copying, it's just a shorthand for `const mana = this.state.mana`. Your second line makes a shallow copy of `this.state.mana`, and then assigns the new object to `mana`.