# I want my products to change its currency when I select a different currency from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want price props passed in Main.js to change its currency symbol and adjust its price according to the currency I select from drop-down menu in Navbar.js. For example, my default currency is USD$ so the price of the first Mainproduct is "$149" if I select "EUR(€)" from drop-down menu in the Navbar Mainproduct price should change to "€(149 divide or multiply by Euro rates".
here is the code:

App.js:

```
import './App.css'
import Main from './components/Main';
import Top from './components/Top';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Top />
      <Main />
    </>
  )
}
```

Main.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Main.css'

const Main = (props) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <Mainproduct price="$149" />
        <Mainproduct price="$49" />
        <Mainproduct price="$65" />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Main
```

Top.js:

```
import React from "react";

import "./Top.css";


import Navbar from "./Navbar";
const Top = () => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Top">
        
        <div className="topnav">
        <div className="cart">
      
      </div>
          <Navbar/>
          <div className="Text">
            <h1>GLASSES AVAILABLE IN <br /> MANY VARIETIES</h1>
            <p>Discover perfect optics for yourself</p>
          </div>
          <div className="downarrow">
            <button >
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/expand-arrow--v2.png" alt="arrow" /></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Top;
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./Navbar.css";
const Navbar = () => {
  const [listopen, setListopen] = useState(false)
  const Dropdown = () => {
    setListopen(!listopen)
  }
  let menuRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (listopen) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
        if (!menuRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
          setListopen(false)

        }

      })
    }

  });



  const [btnText, setBtnText] = useState("USD($)")
  const handleOptionClick = (txt) => {
    setBtnText(txt);
    setListopen(!listopen)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <div ref={menuRef} className="dropdown">
              <li><button className="dropbtn" onClick={() => Dropdown()}  >{btnText}
              </button></li>
              <div className="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown" style={{ display: listopen === false ? 'none' : 'block' }}>
                <a onClick={() => handleOptionClick("AUD($)")}>AUD($)</a>
                <a onClick={() => handleOptionClick("CAD($)")}>CAD($)</a>
                <a onClick={() => handleOptionClick("EUR(€)")}>EUR(€)</a>
                <a onClick={() => handleOptionClick("AUD(£)")}>AUD(£)</a>
                <a onClick={() => handleOptionClick("USD($)")}>USD($)</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>

        </nav>
      </header>
    </>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to make things dynamic, probably the easiest way to do this is to have an array of `currency` objects.

```js
const currencies = [
  {
    name: "USD",
    symbol: "$",
    conversionRate: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "EUR",
    symbol: "€",
    conversionRate: 1.01,
  },
  ...
];
```

Splitting the currency data into smaller pieces will help us later when we want to display them in the UI.

Since we want the selected currency to be accessible in both `Top` and `Main` we'll add the state to the `App` component. You can set the default state to the first currency.

```js
import { currencies } from "./data";

const App = () => {
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState(currencies[0]);

  return (
    <>
      <Top currency={currency} onCurrencyChange={setCurrency} />
      <Main currency={currency} />
    </>
  );
};
```

In `Main` we pass the currency to the `Mainproduct` like so. I changed the `price` prop to `priceInDollars` and also only has the number value instead of "$149".

```js
const Main = ({ currency }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <Mainproduct currency={currency} priceInDollars="149" />
        <Mainproduct currency={currency} priceInDollars="49" />
        <Mainproduct currency={currency} priceInDollars="65" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

In the `Mainproduct` can use our `currency` object to calculate the actual price. We also display the symbol of the currency.

```js
const Mainproduct = ({ priceInDollars, currency }) => {
  const price = priceInDollars * currency.conversionRate;

  return (
    <h2>
      {currency.symbol}
      {price}
    </h2>
  );
};
```

In the `Top` you can just pass down the `currency` and `onCurrencyChange` to the `Navbar`

```js
const Top = ({ onCurrencyChange, currency }) => {
  return (
    ...
    <Navbar onCurrencyChange={onCurrencyChange} currency={currency} />
    ...
  );
};
```

Then in the `Navbar` you can use these props to update and display the different currencies. In the handleClick function we change the state with the new currency object.

Here again we use the `currencies` array to map and render all the currency options to the dropdown.

```js
import { currencies } from './data';

const Navbar = ({ onCurrencyChange, currency }) => {
  ...

  const handleOptionClick = (curr) => {
    onCurrencyChange(curr);
    setListopen(!listopen);
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <li>
      <button className="dropbtn" onClick={() => Dropdown()}>
        {currency.name}
      </button>
    </li>
    <div
      className="dropdown-content"
      id="myDropdown"
      style={{ display: listopen === false ? "none" : "block" }}
    >
      {currencies.map((curr) => (
        <a onClick={() => handleOptionClick(curr)} key={curr.name}>
          {curr.name}({curr.symbol})
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
    ...
  );
};
```

This works quite well but if you would like to avoid "prop drilling" you could take a look at some library like [Jotai](https://jotai.org/) to manage this state without the "prop drilling".

Hope this helps you with your project!

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked for me 100% but  I also have to pass props in Mainproduct.js but if I pass it like this ({ onCurrencyChange, currency, props } ) it doesn't seems to work could also help me with this?

Comment: What is happening with the "props" is that they're being destructured. `({ a, b })` this way you can use the variable by only using the name, this would be the same as `(props)` and then using it like `props.a` and `props.b` I have found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055987/destructuring-state-props-in-react) and this [freeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-basics-of-destructuring-props-in-react-a196696f5477/) which both explain this concept really well.